# Vitest mocking: TypeError: window.URL.createObjectURL is not a function

Tags: reactjs, testing, react-testing-library, vitest

I'm testing with vitest. This module `node_modules/azure-maps-control/dist/atlas.min.js` uses `window.URL.createObjectURL`

And I'm geting this error `TypeError: window.URL.createObjectURL is not a function`

I tryied mocking like this, including the commented ways.

```
beforeAll(() => {

  //   window.URL.createObjectURL = vi.fn();
  //   global.window.URL.createObjectURL = vi.fn();
  //   vi.spyOn(window.URL, 'createObjectURL');

  vi.stubGlobal('URL', {
    createObjectURL: vi.fn(),
    revokeObjectURL: vi.fn(),
    toString: () => 'URL',
    valueOf: () => 'URL',
  });
});
```

This is the test:

```
describe('ClinetPortfolio component', () => {
  it('should render ClinetPortfolio', () => {
    const el = renderWithGlobalContext(<ClientPortifolio />, {
      providerProps: {
        value: {
          state: {},
        },
      },
      route: '/',
    });

    expect(true).toBeFalsy();
  });
});
```

None of it worked. I still get the error. Can someone help me understand this?

Answer (score 1):

You can, actually, mock the whole "azure-maps-control" lib (that way, every call would point to the mock previously made).

Do the following:

```
vi.mock('azure-maps-control', () => ({__esModule: true, default: () = <div />,}));
```

That approach would, probably, works with any lib when having a similar issue, as the following:

```
vi.mock('react-apexcharts', () => ({__esModule: true, default: () = <div />,}));
```